# unpivot of json array in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table:

```
id | items
1  | [{"customer_id": 1}, {"customer_id": 2}]
```

how can I transform it into this in Redshift:

```
id | customer_id
1 | 1
1 | 2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are unnesting a super array and the AWS docs describe how to do this here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

This will basically make a new row for each element in the top array of your data. Then you can apply your selection SQL of the individual fields that you want to extract.

You don't mention the data type of the source json, text or super, but RS SHOULD cast text to super be default.  If not you can explicitly cast to super.